# setState not updating in function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript, flux

I've read many posts concerning this issue, something about `this.setState` being an asynchronous call, so it doesn't re-render every time. How do I approach this problem given the following context:

```
getInitialState: () ->
    return {
        page: ""
    }

choose: (event) ->
    console.log(@props.id) # This is the correct id that I want to pass into state
    @setState({
        page: @props.id # @state.page isn't being set to @props.id 
    })

render: () ->
    return (
        <button onClick={@choose}>Click me</button>
    )
```

I've tried to `bind` the onClick call like `onClick={@choose.bind(@)}` but it seems that React already does this automatically. How do I properly set the state in `choose()` after I click on the button?

SOLUTION: this is the child component which is calling a parent component, so the `state` got lost somewhere in there. All I had to do was to call pass down the `id` from the parent component as props and access it through there.

Comment: You aren't using this.state.page anywhere in your example, so It's a bit hard to know what's not working.

Comment: This could should work fine, what is not working? In your render if you `console.log(this.state.page)` does it not show the id you want?

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems correct. `setState` is not guaranteed to be synchronous, its execution might be delayed. It means that if you try to access `@state.name` right after `@setState` in your code, you gonna get old value

```
choose: (event) ->
  console.log(@props.id) # This is the correct id that I want to pass into state
  @setState({
     page: @props.id # @state.page isn't being set to @props.id 
  })
  console.log(@state.name) # here's old value
```

So you should use second parameter of the `@setState`, which is callback function which will be called right after updating state, so

```
choose: (event) ->
  console.log(@props.id) # This is the correct id that I want to pass into state
  @setState({
     page: @props.id # @state.page isn't being set to @props.id 
  }, () => 
      console.log(@state.name) # <-- updated value here!
  )
  console.log(@state.name) # here's old value
```